# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' error

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am not sure where I am wrong with my code
I could really use help.

```
# this program will get hourly rate, pay rate validate.
# and then will calculate the gross pay.

pay = [7.50, 18.26]
time = [0, 41]

def main():
    getRate(pay)
    getHours(time)
    grossPay(pay, time)

def getRate(pay):
    pay_rate = float(input('Enter your hourly pay rate: '))
    while pay_rate < 7.50 or pay_rate > 18.25:
        print('Pay rate must be between $7.50 and $18.25')
        print('Enter a valid pay rate.')

        pay_rate = float(input('Enter your hourly pay rate: '))

def getHours(time):
    get_hours = float(input('Enter hours worked: '))
    while get_hours < 0 or get_hours > 40:
        print('Hours must be between 0 and 40!')
        print('Enter a valid number of hours.')

        get_hours = float(input('Enter hours worked: '))

def grossPay(pay_rate, get_hours):
    result = pay_rate * get_hours
    print(result)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your functions, you never return the results of your pay rate or your hours.

Change your `main` function to include saving the return values, like

```
def main():
    rate = getRate(pay)
    hours = getHours(time)
    grossPay(rate, hours)
```

And in your `getRate` and `getHours` functions, include a return statement of your `pay_rate` and `get_hours` variables, like

```
def getRate(pay):
    pay_rate = float(input('Enter your hourly pay rate: '))
    while pay_rate < 7.50 or pay_rate > 18.25:
        print('Pay rate must be between $7.50 and $18.25')
        print('Enter a valid pay rate.')

        pay_rate = float(input('Enter your hourly pay rate: '))

    return pay_rate  # As you want to get the value captured back to where the function was called from
```

Comment: I added a return in getRate and getHours but still having issues with the grossPay call. grossPay(rate, hours) line 33, in grossPay result = time * pay TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'– Sandra Luz Rivera-Guillen2 mins ago   edit

Comment: Is your grossPay function using the variables supplied to it, or is it using the global `time` and `pay` variables you have at the top of your code ? Your traceback snippet suggests the latter, and you're trying to do `[0, 41] * [7.50, 18.26]` instead of using the supplied `rate` & `hours` variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must redefine

```
def grossPay(pay_rate, get_hours):
    for hrs, rate in zip(pay_rate, get_hrs):
      result = hrs * rate
      print(result)
```

Comment: where does the Zip come in?

Comment: sorry it's typo error it's zip inbuilt function in python.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this line from `grossPay`:

```
result = pay_rate * get_hours
```

because you are calling `grossPay` like

```
grossPay([7.50, 18.26], [0, 41])
```

Your functions aren't doing what you think they do... you are passing an argument, and generating a new value, but you are not returning that value entered by the user.

Comment: I added a return in getRate and getHours but still having issues with the grossPay call.
    grossPay(rate, hours)
 line 33, in grossPay
    result = time * pay
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'